# Sorting through a column in Postgres which is not numeric

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using postgres and i want to sort the data using order by but there is an issue with the sorting which i am unable to figure out.

I have a column which is character varying and the values in that column are.

`_________
|ID  |Name|
|1   | ABC|
|5   | ABC|
|2   | ABC|
|7-A | ABC|
|2-A | ABC|
|3   | ABC|
-----------`

I want the results as following

`_________
|ID  |Name|
|1   | ABC|
|2   | ABC|
|2-A | ABC|
|3   | ABC|
|5   | ABC|
|7   | ABC|
-----------`